# Spark Programme to Count Letters

Tags: java, apache-spark

I write the spark program  to count the words but now I want to Count letters instead of word. Can Anyone please tell me what do I have to change in the following code:

Here is the code to count words

```
public class WordCount {


static class SplitFunction implements FlatMapFunction<String, String>
 {
 public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
    return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
  }
 }

public static void main(String[] args)
{

SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
sparkConf.setAppName("Spark WordCount example using Java");

sparkConf.setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

JavaRDD<String> textFile = sparkContext.textFile("input.txt");

JavaRDD<String> words = textFile.flatMap(new SplitFunction());

JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
      public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
      }
     });
 JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey(
    new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
      public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a + b;
      }
    });


counts.saveAsTextFile("output");
sparkContext.stop();
sparkContext.close();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use Java as it is a pain. Use Scala is my advice.

If you look at this wordcount example from the docs:

```
JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://...");
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = textFile
    .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator())
    .mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<>(word, 1))
    .reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...");
```

Then if you split like so: `s.split(""))`, then you will get all characters *including separators*.

You can then filter the counts of the separators out subsequently. You may wish to change the names in the code, of course.